# JIRA Labels with fixed set of values

Tags: jira

We have labels in JIRA. This "labels" is predefined field and not a custom field as I observed. 
The labels are auto-complete fields and any value can be assigned to it. 
I want these labels to pick values only from a set of values. Is there a way to do this?
Also, is it possible that the set of values can be uploaded from a list/excel/csv?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to add a custom field with your required settings (a single value or maybe a multi-pick selection).

I use the Jira Cloud solution and I'm not aware of any way to import values into custom fields. If you have a local installation and have a developer to help you might be able to find a way to import them but I'm guessing it might be easier/faster to do it manually even if there are a hundred or so.